# php: read an http url and write it to pdf

Tags: php, url, pdf, stream

im using php

I want to read a url ex http://www.cnn.com

create a new pdf and store to the server

Comment: Go for it! What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/. It's open source, and seems to be based on the WebKit engine, which is used in many browsers today (Chrome, Safari, iOS, Android). It also has **PHP bindings**!

Here's the link to the GitHub page: https://github.com/mreiferson/php-wkhtmltox.

Comment: @Blender: wht would be the process for shared hosting linux from scratch with php ??

Comment: @user326096 you got solution ??   could you help me for this same problem >

Comment: @PuzzledBoy: Why would you even use LFS for hosting a website?

Answer (score -4):

You can't just create a pdf from a web page. Especially if you don't want to make a jpeg of the whole thing and stuff that in a pdf.

Comment: well im reading from an external site about 12 page worth of data