# Get HTML with current styles (maybe inlined) of a page that finished rendering and finished running scripts

Tags: php, html, css

I need to get the HTML with current styles (maybe inlined) of a page that finished rendering and finished running scripts, using a server side application which will be given just an URL (no extra information such as cookies, no POSTs, no impeding forms, etc.).

A bridge/proxy to a temporarily running browser or a stand alone utility using a browser library is an accepted solution (however, the chosen browser or browser library must be available on all major platforms, and must be able to run without an OS GUI beeing present or installed).

An optional requirement is to remove all scripts afterwards (there are already stand alone solutions for this, adding it here because maybe the given answer will be able to remove scripts while rendering or something like that).

**How do I get a snapshot in HTML+CSS in a single .html file of the curent HTML document with the current styles (maybe inlined) and current images (using [data URI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt))?**

If it can be done using pure PHP it would be a plus (although I doubt it, I haven't found anything interesting).

**Edit:** I know how to load HTTP resources and get the HTML for an URL, that's not what I'm looking for ;)

**Edit 2**
Example input HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/example.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/example.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener("load",
                function(event){
                    document.title="New title";

                    document.getElementById("pic_0").style.border="0px";
                }
            );
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            p{
                color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
        <p>
            <img 
                alt="" 
                style="border: 1px" 
                id="pic_0" 
                src="http://linuxgazette.net/144/misc/john/helloworld.png"
            >
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New title</title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

        <style type="text/css">
            b{font-weight: bold}
        </style>

        <style type="text/css">
            p{
                color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
        <p>
            <img 
                alt="" 
                style="border: 0px" 
                id="pic_0" 
                src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoBAMAAAB+0KVeAAAAK3RFWHRDcmVhdGlvbiBUaW1lAFYgMzEgYXVnLiAyMDEyIDE3OjU4OjU1ICswMjAwWMdbPwAAAAd0SU1FB9wIHw8ABeoUyU4AAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAEZ0FNQQAAsY8L/GEFAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAXklEQVR42uWQUQ6AMAhD6Q3a+19WqsawwMf+NLEfy3iDlC7idTGQp/YglFAsUMqSwjlQOhN3mIMTHDq70SeEWBbt0EG8POWkDySvmCh/SssvNfwIfb+hFmgjFKPf6gDQBAQ368m09AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
            >
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice how the `<title>` tag changed, how `border: 1px` became `border: 0px`, how the image URL was transformed into a [data URI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt).

For example, some of these transformations (inline CSS and `<title>` tag) can be observed when inspecting the document using the Google Chrome inspector.

**Edit 3**: Replacing external resources with on-page ones (styles and images) and removing javascript is an easy part. The hard part is computing the CSS style after running javascript.

**Edit 4** Maybe this could be done using injected javascript (still need browser control though)?

Comment: You need bindings to a rendering engine [e.g. Webkit] - this may be a nice start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362855/php-read-an-http-url-and-write-it-to-pdf

Comment: @moonwave99 Yes I know about wkhtmltopdf :) If that's the start I have  a lot of work to do...:(

Comment: Well I think that rendering to PDF is a plus - there should be a step when they get pure html+css in the code, if you dare to dive into the library you may get the data you need ^^

Comment: Actually they have a wkhtmltoimage utility in the works. I'll study that, I think it might have a little less restrictions than when rendering to PDFs. Thanks :) (a dirty solution would be converting back to HTML from PDF (it will ruin most documents though, I think)).

Comment: Out of curiosity: Are you trying to make some kind of cache like the google's one?

Comment: @rcdmk No, yet it would fit such a task perfectly. A solution to this problem would have many applications.

Comment: I answered my own question, if you're interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is a headless (GUI-less) WebKit with JavaScript API.
It runs on all major platforms, as I requested in my question.

It can run Javascript scripts to control the GUI-less web browser. It has a powerful API, and lots and lots of examples.

In my spare time over the last 2-3 days I wrote the solution to my question, and it covers all requirements beautifully. I haven't found a webpage for which it wouldn't work.

.

Usage, command line:

```
phantomjs save_as_html.js http://stackoverflow.com/q/12215844/584490 saved.html
```

.

Javascript is allowed to run for `n` seconds after everything else loads, it should work even for web pages generated entirely by javascript.

.

Notes:

- Where possible, XHR loading of resources is prefered over HTML5's canvas rendering because of reduced file size and preventing quality loss (reusing original files is better than anything).
- `<link>` and `<img>` tags are kept in place, and `data:` URIs are used inside the href and src attributes respectively, instead of URLs. The same is true for `background-image`, which is read using getComputedStyle() on all DOM nodes.
- `<script>` tags and event handler attributes are removed.
- `<link>` tags with `rel="alternative"` are removed also (maybe they shouldn't be, and instead be fixed into an absolute URL, if relative).
- `<iframe>` is currently not handled, and its src attribute is beeing set to `about:blank`.

.

*Beware all cross site scripting security restrictions are lifted, so that all resources can be loaded. Make sure you don't try to save malicious webpages while using some secret credentials of your Facebook account :).*

.

**`save_as_html.js`** contents:

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/12256190/584490

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) { console.log(msg); };

var system = require('system');
var address, output, size;


if (system.args.length!=3)
{
    console.log('Usage: save_as_html.js URL filename');
    phantom.exit(1);
}
else
{
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];

    page.viewportSize = {    
        width: 1680, 
        height: 1050,
    };

    //SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
    //Enable cross site scripting:
    page.settings.XSSAuditingEnabled=false;
    page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled=true;
    page.settings.webSecurityEnabled=false;

    page.settings.userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1";
    page.settings.ignoreSslErrors=true;

    page.open(address, function (status){
        if (status!=='success')
        {
            console.log("Unable to load URL, returned status: "+status);
            phantom.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            window.setTimeout(function (){
                page.evaluate(function(){
                    var nodeList=document.getElementsByTagName("*");

                    var arrEventHandlerAttributes=[
                        "onblur", "onchange", "onclick", "ondblclick", "onfocus", "onkeydown", "onkeyup", "onkeypress", "onkeyup","onload",
                        "onmousedown", "onmousemove", "onmouseout", "onmouseover", "onmouseup", "onreset", "onselect", "onsubmit", "onunload"
                    ];


                    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/7372816/584490
                    var base64Encode=function(str)
                    {
                        var CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
                        var out = "", i = 0, len = str.length, c1, c2, c3;
                        while (i < len) {
                            c1 = str.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
                            if (i == len) {
                                out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
                                out += CHARS.charAt((c1 & 0x3) << 4);
                                out += "==";
                                break;
                            }
                            c2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
                            if (i == len) {
                                out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
                                out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
                                out += CHARS.charAt((c2 & 0xF) << 2);
                                out += "=";
                                break;
                            }
                            c3 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
                            out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
                            out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
                            out += CHARS.charAt(((c2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((c3 & 0xC0) >> 6));
                            out += CHARS.charAt(c3 & 0x3F);
                        }
                        return out;
                    };


                    for(var n=nodeList.length-1; n>0; n--)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var el=nodeList[n];

                            if(el.nodeName=="IMG" && el.src.substr(0, 5)!="data:")
                            {
                                /*var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");

                                canvas.width=parseInt(el.width);
                                canvas.height=parseInt(el.height);

                                var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
                                ctx.drawImage(el, 0, 0);
                                el.src=canvas.toDataURL();*/

                                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

                                xhr.open(
                                    "get",
                                    el.src,
                                    /*Asynchronous*/ false
                                );

                                xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");

                                xhr.send(null);

                                var strResponseContentType=xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-type").split(";")[0].replace(/[^a-z0-9\/-]/gi, "");
                                el.src="data:"+strResponseContentType+";base64,"+base64Encode(xhr.responseText);
                            }
                            else if(el.nodeName=="LINK")
                            {
                                if(el.rel=="alternate")
                                {
                                    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
                                }
                                else if(el.href.substr(0, 5)!="data:")
                                {
                                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

                                    xhr.open(
                                        "get",
                                        el.href,
                                        /*Asynchronous*/ false
                                    );

                                    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");

                                    xhr.send(null);

                                    //var strResponseContentType=xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-type").split(";")[0].replace(/[^a-z0-9\/-]/gi, "");
                                    //el.href="data:"+strResponseContentType+";base64,"+base64Encode(xhr.responseText);
                                    el.href="data:"+el.type+";base64,"+base64Encode(xhr.responseText);
                                }

                                continue;
                            }
                            else if(el.nodeName=="SCRIPT")
                            {
                                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);

                                continue;
                            }
                            else if(el.nodeName=="IFRAME")
                            {
                                el.src="about:blank";

                                continue;
                            }

                            for(var z=arrEventHandlerAttributes.length-1; z>=0; z--)
                                el.removeAttribute(arrEventHandlerAttributes[z]);

                            var strBackgroundImageURL=window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("background-image").replace("/[\s]/g", "");
                            if(strBackgroundImageURL.substr(0, 4)=="url(" && strBackgroundImageURL.substr(4, 5)!="data:")
                            {
                                strBackgroundImageURL=strBackgroundImageURL.substr(4, strBackgroundImageURL.length-5);

                                /*var imageTemp=document.createElement("img");
                                imageTemp.src=strBackgroundImageURL;

                                imageTemp.onload=function(e){
                                    var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");

                                    canvas.width=parseInt(imageTemp.width);
                                    canvas.height=parseInt(imageTemp.height);

                                    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
                                    ctx.drawImage(imageTemp, 0, 0);
                                    el.style.backgroundImage="url("+canvas.toDataURL()+")";
                                };

                                if (imageTemp.complete)
                                    imageTemp.onload();
                                */

                                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

                                xhr.open(
                                    "get",
                                    strBackgroundImageURL,
                                    /*Asynchronous*/ false
                                );

                                xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");

                                xhr.send(null);

                                var strResponseContentType=xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-type").split(";")[0].replace(/[^a-z0-9\/-]/gi, "");
                                el.style.backgroundImage="url("+"data:"+strResponseContentType+";base64,"+base64Encode(xhr.responseText)+")";
                            }

                            if(el.nodeName=="A")
                            {
                                el.href="#";//TODO convert relative paths to absolute ones (keep URLs);
                                el.setAttribute("onclick", "return false;");//TODO: remove this when the above is fixed.
                            }
                            else if(el.nodeName=="FORM")
                            {
                                el.setAttribute("action", "");
                                el.setAttribute("onsubmit", "return false;");
                            }
                        }
                        catch(error)
                        {
                            //what can be done about it?
                        }
                    }
                });

                require("fs").write(output, page.content, "w");

                phantom.exit();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use native `btoa` instead of self-made `base64Encode` function.